# how to loop over a nested array and add parts of it to different divs with the same id javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a json a nested array that I would like to print parts of it to a div that has the same id. I had thought of doing a foreach loop to loop to loop of the nested array. In order to add it to each div I thought about giving each div a dataset but when I do this and then add a for loop after the foreach loop all the data set is being set to the last id in the array. What should I do?

```
    const data = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "movie_name": "last holiday",
            "date": "2023-10-29",
            "length": ["1 hour 30"],
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "movie_name": "pitch perfect",
            "date": "2023-04-24",
            "length": ["2 hours"]
        }
    ];
```

```
<div class="fun">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div class="fun">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

```
 data.forEach(e => {
    for (let i = 0; i < fun.length; i++) {
        fun[i].dataset.id = e.id;
        if (fun[i].dataset.id === e.id) {
    fun[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",`
    <h4 class="cardTitle">${e.movie_name}</h4>
    <h5 class="cardSubtitle">${e.date}</h5>`);
}
    
  }
})
```

I want the following output to be

```html
<div class="fun" data-id="1">
<p>Hello</p>
<h3>last holiday</h3>
<h4>2023-10-29</h4>
</div>

<div class="fun" data-id="2">
<p>Hello</p>
<h3>pitch perfect</h3>
<h4>2023-04-24</h4>
</div>
```

What is the best way to do this

Comment: If you need to filter by run time, I suggest you store the minutes and used them to compare to a minimum run time. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/v160y4p5/) example. It makes use of data attributes to store information on the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `document.querySelectorAll('.fun')` to get all the `divs` with `fun` class, you can then loop over `data` and use that index to insert your content to `allFuns[i]` for each object.

```js
const data = [
    {"id": 1, "movie_name": "last holidy", "date": "2023-10-29", "length": ["1 hour 30"], },
    {"id": 2, "movie_name": "pitch perfect", "date": "2023-04-24", "length": ["2 hours"] }
];

const allFuns = document.querySelectorAll('.fun');

for (let i in data) {
    let obj = data[i];
    
    allFuns[i].dataset.id = obj.id;
    allFuns[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",`
        <h4 class="cardTitle">${obj.movie_name}</h4>
        <h5 class="cardSubtitle">${obj.date}</h5>
    `);
}
```

```html
<div class="fun">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div class="fun">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div class="fun">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

This generates the following HTML:

```html
<body>
    <div class="fun" data-id="1">
        <p>Hello</p>

        <h4 class="cardTitle">last holidy</h4>
        <h5 class="cardSubtitle">2023-10-29</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="fun" data-id="2">
        <p>Hello</p>

        <h4 class="cardTitle">pitch perfect</h4>
        <h5 class="cardSubtitle">2023-04-24</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="fun">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot about just using a for in loop. Thank you